# If $X$ and $Y$ are ordinals and $Y\subset X$, then $Y$ is a section of $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, ordinals

I'm studying ordinals via Cameron's *Sets, Logic and Categories*. On p. 42, Cameron works to prove that

> If $X$ and $Y$ are ordinals and $Y\subset X$, then $Y$ is a section of $X$.
>
> > Proof: Take $a$ to be the least element of $X\setminus Y$. Then $X_a\subseteq Y$. [The proof follows by showing that $Y\subseteq X_a$ by applying the trichotomy rule to $a$.]

I have two questions about this proof.

1. How does $X_a\subseteq Y$ follow immediately from $a$ being the least element of $X\setminus Y$? It isn't intuitive to me.
2. Wouldn't the proof proceed more simply as follows? Let $a$ be the least element of $X\setminus Y$. So $\forall y\in Y$, $y<a$ since $Y$ is an ordinal. Now $\forall x\in X$, if $x>a$ or $x=a$, $x\notin Y$. So $Y=\{x\in X:x<a\}=X_a$

Comment: To get the set difference operator $\setminus$, use `\setminus`.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By our choice of $a$ as the least element of $X\setminus Y,$ we have for any $b\in X_a$ that $b\in X=(X\cap Y)\cup(X\setminus Y)$ and $b<a,$ so $b\notin X\setminus Y,$ and so $b\in X\cap Y=Y.$ Thus $X_a\subseteq Y.$

Your approach starts off fine, applying the trichotomy rule to $a,$ and concluding that $Y\subseteq X_a.$ However, it doesn't show that $X_a\subseteq Y,$ only that $Y\subseteq X_a$ in another way (by contrapositive).

Comment: Thank you; the first part is very clear. (And I have made the $x$ vs $X$ correction.) Are you saying that $Y=\{x\in X:x<a\}\subseteq X_a$? But doesn't $\{x\in X:x<a\}=X$ by definition?

Comment: Not quite. Your second part says that if $x\in X\setminus X_a,$ then $x\in X\setminus Y.$ Since $Y$ and $X_a$ are subsets of $X$ (by hypothesis and definition, respectively), this is equivalent to saying that if $x\notin X_a,$ then $x\notin Y.$ This is simply the contrapositive of (and so equivalent to) $Y\subseteq X_a.$